# Python Reading and writing CSV and modifying lines

Tags: python, file, csv, file-writing

While reading a csv file, why can't I take a key's variable and add one to it, then re-write to the csv to write over that line?
(Line labeled #PROBLEM PORTION is the line I'm referring too)

```
def userExists():
count = 0
global fieldnames,plyname,plylname,scorefile
fieldnames = ['score','fn','ln']
if os.path.isfile("scorefiles/"+scorefile+".csv") == True:
    with open("scorefiles/"+scorefile+'.csv', 'r') as csv_file:   #File being opened
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)                     #File being read as csv_reader(where the contents are)

        for line in csv_reader:                                   # Loop through the lines
            print(line['fn'],line['ln'],line['score'])
            if line['fn'] == plyname.lower():                          # Does CSV First Name == Player's First name?
                with open("scorefiles/"+scorefile+'.csv', 'r+') as newFile:  # Open CSV 
                    newFileWriter = csv.DictWriter(newFile,fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=',')# Create a writer for the file
                    newFileWriter.writeheader()
                    for line in csv_reader:
                        line['score'] = int(line['score']) + 1 #PROBLEM PORTION
                        newFileWriter.writerow(line)
                print(line['fn'])       
                count = count + 1

        if count == 0:                                            # if the count == 0 (player doesn't exist), add the player to the csv.
            with open("scorefiles/"+scorefile+'.csv', 'a') as newFile:  # Open CSV
                newFileWriter = csv.writer(newFile)                     # Create a writer for the file
                newFileWriter.writerow([1,plyname.lower(),plylname.lower()]) #Write to the csv
                print("Wrote player name to save data.")


        print('Count: ',count)
else:
    #File path doesn't exist so it creates the new file
    createcsv()
```

Comment: Also, I'm very new to python so if you could actually explain the problem if you figure it out, that would be extremely helpful and greatly appreciated!

Comment: "without figuring out why it's not letting me": What exactly is happening? Do you get an error message? If so, include the complete error message into your question

Comment: There's no error message, the line where i've marked "PROBLEM PORTION" is the line that I was talking about where i'm trying to take the current score of that line (eg whatever the current value is) and just add one to it, and then push it to that position in the csv file, so it would just rewrite the line with the correct score, but it's just... not writing anything other than the 1 to the line (one from it being set originally, which you can see in the count==0 conditional)

Comment: I think you are over complicating the problem. You have a `for line in csv_reader:` to loop through the lines in your file, and search for the player you are interested in. Then when you find that line, you have another `for line in csv_reader:`. The second `for` loop will read the next line after the line that you found for the player. So you are not changing the original line that you searched for.

Comment: Also, reading and writing the same file with different readers and writers at the same time is a bad idea. If your file is not huge, try reading the entire file and holding it in memory, then make your changes in memory, then write the entire file back out with the changes.

Comment: Well can you give me an example of how to fix this, I'm clueless, I've now tried removing that and moving everything back a tab and it was adding, but the problem started being that it's just writing over the other lines and putting that data in their place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this should work:

```
import csv
import os

plyname = 'Fred'
plylname = 'Flintstone'
scorefile = 'scores'


def userExists():
    count = 0
    global fieldnames,plyname,plylname,scorefile
    fieldnames = ['score','fn','ln']
    theWholeFile = []    # this will hold the entire csv file with changes
    if os.path.isfile("scorefiles/"+scorefile+".csv") == True:
        with open("scorefiles/"+scorefile+'.csv', 'r') as csv_file:   #File being opened
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)                     #File being read as csv_reader(where the contents are)

            for line in csv_reader:                                   # Loop through the lines
                print(line['fn'],line['ln'],line['score'])
                if line['fn'] == plyname.lower():                          # Does CSV First Name == Player's First name?
                    line['score'] = int(line['score']) + 1 #PROBLEM PORTION
                    print(line['fn'])
                    count = count + 1
                theWholeFile.append(line)   # add every line to theWholeFile
            csv_file.close()     # done reading the csv file, so close it

            if count == 0:                                            # if the count == 0 (player doesn't exist), add the player to the csv.
                with open("scorefiles/" + scorefile + '.csv', 'a') as newFile:  # Open CSV
                    newFileWriter = csv.writer(newFile)  # Create a writer for the file
                    newFileWriter.writerow([1, plyname.lower(), plylname.lower()])  # Write to the csv
                    print("Wrote player name to save data.")
                    newFile.close()
            else:  # re-write the entire file (with changes)
                with open("scorefiles/" + scorefile + '.csv', 'w') as newFile:  # Open CSV
                    newFileWriter = csv.DictWriter(newFile, fieldnames)  # Create a writer for the file
                    newFileWriter.writeheader()
                    for line in theWholeFile:
                        newFileWriter.writerow(line)
                    newFile.close()



            print('Count: ',count)
    else:
        #File path doesn't exist so it creates the new file
        createcsv()

def createcsv():
    pass

userExists()
```

Note that the csv file is never opened more than once at a time. The entire file is read and saved in `theWholeFile`. If the searched for player is found, changes are made to  `theWholeFile` while reading, then the entire file is re-written using a `csv.DictWriter`. If the searched for player is not found, the player is just appened to the scores file using a `csv.Writer`.

Comment: There ya go! .. so something I've came across is the sorted function doesn't seem to be working correctly for me... it sorts... but it's not putting them in the correct sorted order...in another reader not the same function, i've got this as the sorting method
    scorelist = sorted(csv_reader, key=operator.itemgetter('score'), reverse=True)
Essentially it's bunching everything together but it's not returning the scores highest to lowest, or it will throw a random score where it's not supposed to be, the printing is just score, fn, ln like the formatting ...

Comment: @JamesB That works correctly for me. Keep in mind that `csv_reader` can only be used once. That is, you can use `csv_reader` to go through all the lines of a csv file just once. If you use the same reader a second time, as in `for line in csv_reader`, you will get no lines.

Comment: I figured out the problem is the operator.itemgetter('score') actually only grabs the first CHARACTER and goes off of that, so it would work up until a player would reach 10 (since the first character is a 1 and not counting the entire number it would sort as if the players score was 1),  this was fixed by adding in int() around the key, but i did swap it to lambda and rows instead.